# One login page for multiple WARs

Tags: maven, authentication, jakarta-ee, glassfish

For an application Java EE multi module, we search to package all module on one EAR like this:
 - Common-war : all common pages and classes (errors pages, login, common library, …)

- war1   :  only pages and classes module 1
- war2   :  only pages and classes module 2
- war3   :  only pages and classes module 3
- …

After research, we found that each WAR has its own context, hence there is no session sharing between WARs except by using Single Sign-on who need to use the same `realm-name` described in the `web.xml` of each WAR.

1. Is there a way to use one page login for all WARs?
2. Is it possible to use one web.xml for all WARs?

We use: GlassFish 3.1, JSF, EJB, Maven.

Comment: Have you considered using a custom cookie that helps you remember users across these wars? That can be possible using the same domain for all of these cookies. However, you'd still need to have code that reads/writes this cookie and validates the war-specific sessions of web modules.

Comment: Yes, The single sign-on feature utilizes HTTP cookies to transmit a token that associates each request with the saved user identity, but our need is to use a single login page of common WAR